# POST Data is being stripped of HTML Entities

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've got a standard login form submitting data to a Codeigniter function to do the authentication.. Problem is, the data seems to be being stripped of HTML Entities before it even hits the function.. Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but I'd have thought that the parameters in config.php were just relevant to Codeigniter functions, I.E. It would be relevant to $this->input->post NOT $_POST.. Eitherway, in my config.php I've got

`$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;`

If I submit the form, the data that I'm submitting in the input fields is:

```
$_POST['user'] = 'user';
$_POST['password'] = 'password%100';
```

For reference, my form opening tag is:

`<form method="POST" action="<?=site_url('/log-in')?>">`

I've done the following function to test the data:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo sha1('userpassword%100') . '<br />';
echo sha1($_POST['username'] . $_POST['password']) . '<br />';
echo sha1($this->input->post('username', FALSE) . $this->input->post('password', FALSE)) . '<br />';
echo "</pre>";
```

Which gives an output of:

```
Array
(
    [username] => user
    [password] => password0
)
ad45e6412dd3cec23e47bbb48c874cdcfd6d39e7
fa3279bde5d6aba9ed77c6e5b071ff8dde741b92
fa3279bde5d6aba9ed77c6e5b071ff8dde741b92
```

So the top hash is the one that is correct, but the actual data being passed through seems to strip out html entities, I.E. %10 from the password field - $_POST['password'] should be password%100 NOT password0

Can anyone advise me on how to get the correct, un-escaped data?

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: get it yourself directly from POST, and do the filtering yourself. I dont know if CI support custom validators, that will do the validation your way, but you can try to write one. I know that in ZF you can do that.

Comment: If you have a look above, I already have. Both give the same output... If I use $_POST OR $this->input->post()

Comment: Is there an easy way to get some sort of stacktrace as to what the $_POST variables go through before they hit your function?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I've just done a further test and it's definitely something to do with Codeigniter - I wouldn't have thought it should re-write $_POST variables directly, seems to though. I POSTed the data to a php script directly as opposed to through CI and it gave the correct password value.

Comment: if the POST comes already truncated it means that is not sent as it should and the filtering is done in the browser or on the way, so is out of the scope of your script. when you are looking at the raw headers what is sent with the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have also face almost same problem and in that i use $_REQUEST method and its works for me. Please try this hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Pramod, I guess a bit of a horrible hack, but about as horrible as editing the core which is what I've ended up doing after finding the rogue line. I'll accept yours as the solution but I'll post up what I've done as well.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On line 568 of /system/core/Input.php move the remove_invisible_characters function into the `$this->_enable_xss === TRUE` statement.

Previously:

```
    // Remove control characters
    $str = remove_invisible_characters($str);

    // Should we filter the input data?
    if ($this->_enable_xss === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->security->xss_clean($str);
    }
```

Now:

```
    // Should we filter the input data?
    if ($this->_enable_xss === TRUE)
    {
        // Remove control characters
        $str = remove_invisible_characters($str);

        $str = $this->security->xss_clean($str);
    }
```

Hope that helps some others!

Comment: Thanks for the posting solution...It will surely help many who dont have any idea about request method.+1 for that

Comment: -1 This is most certainly a bad idea. Removing checks like this (especially in the core of web frameworks) will open your scripts to all kinds of security vulnerabilities. Don't ever do this!